# Rewinding Argument and Forking lemma

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

In Dan Boneh's crypto book, there is a section describing the "Rewinding Lemma", however I cannot find it explained in other sources on the internet.

How does this differ from the forking lemma?

Comment: I think it's similar to the generalized forking lemma introduced by Bellare and Neven. You may want to take a look.